# Ember. Inject an addon service into additional 'areas'

Tags: service, ember-cli

How would I inject an addon service into other 'places'?

For example, if I install an addon that injects into controllers & components with the code below:

```
export default {
  name: 'notification-messages-service',
    initialize() {
    let application = arguments[1] || arguments[0];
    application.register('notification-messages:service', NotificationMessagesService);

     ['controller', 'component'].forEach(injectionTarget => {
        application.inject(injectionTarget, 'notifications', 'notification-messages:service');
    });
}};
```

How would I then inject the same service (the same singleton) into **services** & **routes** - my requirement is actually inject into a single service, **services:messages**?

I don't believe I can use

```
notifications: Ember.inject.service();
```

because in the addon the service is written as:

```
export default Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({...});
```

I can change the addon, of course, but my changes would be gone once the addon is updated.

Thanks for looking, N

Comment: which addon do you use? let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to inject the addon to my specific service by creating a new initialiser with the code below:

```
export default {
name: 'inject-ember-notification-service',

initialize: function(container, app) {
    app.inject('services:message', 'notifications', 'notification-messages:service');
}
};
```

Fiendishly obtuse, ember!

Thanks to you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
notifications: Ember.inject.service('notification-messages');
```

should work

param for `service` is optional if name of service the same as property name, but it's bette always use it

**P.S.** code above for normal services
in you case code

```
   ['controller', 'component'].forEach(injectionTarget => {
        application.inject(injectionTarget, 'notifications', 'notification-messages:service');
    });
```

means that controllers/components just get new property `notifications`
So inside your controllers/components you can use
`this.get('notifications')`

Comment: Unfortunately, the inject doesn't work (I've tried that1). As in the OP, the service is written as an `ArrayProxy`. `this.get('notifications')` returns `undefined`

Comment: @ninety - which addon you use?

Comment: ember-cli-notifications

Comment: @ninety https://github.com/stonecircle/ember-cli-notifications/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/controllers/application.js#L25 here is example . Did you use in such way? can you give link to your repo?